# EF Code first 4.3 naming convention foreign key

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following entity:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public int GroupID {get; set;}     // navigation property with 
    public Group Group {get; set;}     // foreign key field

    public Adress Adress {get; set;}   // navigation property only

}
```

The table generated from entity framework looks like:

```
ID
GroupID
Adress_ID
```

I don't like, that the column naming for the FK columns is not the same. Can I achieve that both use the same convention either "GroupID, AdressID" or "Group_ID, Adress_ID"?

I use convention over configuration and don't want to use Fluent API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 4.1 to 4.3 doesn't support creating custom conventions, so it's not possible. The only thing you can do (without Fluent API) is probably mapping the foreign property to another column name:

```
[Column("Group_ID")]
public int GroupID {get; set;}
```

Then you have both FK columns with underscore in the database. But - as you can see - you need to overwrite the conventions with data annotations at least.

Defining the second FK column without underscore is only possible with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Address)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("AddressID"));
```

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050590/why-does-ef5-create-foreign-keys-with-id-but-recommend-naming-convention-id-wi/18066373?noredirect=1#18066373`   explains why the column appears