# Why does EF5 create foreign keys with _Id, but recommend naming convention Id without the underscore?

Tags: ef-code-first

I have columns in my database that EF put in for me, that are classname followed by _Id. However much of the documentation recommends that the naming convention for foreign keys is the classname followed by Id without the underscore.

Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258484/ef-code-first-4-3-naming-convention-foreign-key)  I dont want to have both conventions in my database.

Code First creates a foreign key in the database using the pattern [Name of navigation property]_[Primary Key of related class]

Why the 2 apparently inconsistent conventions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every entity that holds a reference to another entity should have a property named `ForeignEntityId` (note the lower case d in Id).

If you set up your entities following the exact pattern of this example, all your columns should be named according to convention:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; } // this property is important
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get a CustomerId property in my order class.  However when assigning a Customer to an Order I simply want to set the Customer navigation property.  It is confusing to also see the CustomerId property.  Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: Why is the CustomerId property important?  Won't the db automatically create a Customer_Id field based on the navigation property alone?